# How can I call the class constructor from a static method?

Tags: constructor, static, abap

In my code I want to call the `CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR` method from the static method `ADD_BOOK`.

However I receive this syntax error:

> The direct call of the special method "CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR" is not
>   possible.

Here is the code:

```
CLASS lcl_books DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS class_constructor.
    CLASS-METHODS add_book.
    ...
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_books IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD class_constructor.
    SELECT * FROM zgib_bmabuecher INTO TABLE gt_return.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD add_book.
    DATA lf_check TYPE n VALUE 0.
    LOOP AT gt_return INTO mf_books.
      IF if_book-isbn = mf_books-isbn.
        lf_check = 1.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
    IF lf_check = 0.
      INSERT zgib_bmabuecher FROM if_book.
    ENDIF.
    lcl_books=>class_constructor( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Comment: For information, in 7.52, the syntax error message is rearranged like this (that changes nothing to the question): "The special method "CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR" cannot be called directly."

Answer (score 8):

You have all the information in the error message. You cannot (german: darfst nicht) call the class constructor explicitly. It is always called automatically and just once whenever the class is used for the first time.

If you want to reuse the coding of the class constructor then put it in another class method, for example like this.

```
CLASS lcl_books DEFINITION.
  "...
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS:
      select_books.
  "...
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_books IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD class_constructor.
    select_books( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD select_books.
    SELECT * FROM zgib_bmabuecher INTO TABLE gt_return.
  ENDMETHOD.
```

Then change your `add_book` method to

```
METHOD add_book.
    DATA lf_check TYPE n VALUE 0.
    LOOP AT gt_return INTO mf_books.
      IF if_book-isbn = mf_books-isbn.
        lf_check = 1.
      ENDIF.
    ENDLOOP.
    IF lf_check = 0.
      INSERT zgib_bmabuecher FROM if_book.
    ENDIF.
    select_books( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```